# Java Swing horizontal layout of components of varying heights

Tags: java, swing

My Java 8 Swing program builds a UI dynamically based on a simple DSL:

```
RADIO(AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;one;two;three) TEXT(B) TEXT(CCCCCC) RADIO(D;four;five;six;seven;eight;9;10)
```

should produce a horizontal sequence of `JRadioButton`s and `JTextField`s like:

```
 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  B             CCCCCC         D
 (*) one           [-----------] [-----------]  (*) four
 ( ) two                                        ( ) five
 ( ) three                                      ( ) six
                                                ( ) seven
                                                ( ) eight
                                                ( ) 9
                                                ( ) 10
```

where width and height of the text fields is the same and the radio fields vary based on values. The field types and order is completely up to the DSL.

My initial `GroupLayout` implementation is simple:

```
Group horizontalGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
fields.forEach(field -> horizontalGroup.addComponent(field));
layout.setHorizontalGroup(horizontalGroup);

Group verticalGroup = layout.createParallelGroup();
fields.forEach(field -> verticalGroup.addComponent(field));
layout.setVerticalGroup(verticalGroup);
```

and the `RADIO` and `TEXT` fields are:

```
private void radioField(JLabel label, List<JRadioButton> radioButtons) {
    GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(this);
    setLayout(gl);

    gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

    Group horizontalGroup = gl.createParallelGroup();
    horizontalGroup.addComponent(label);
    radioButtons.forEach(radioValue -> horizontalGroup.addComponent(radioValue));

    gl.setHorizontalGroup(horizontalGroup);

    SequentialGroup verticalGroup = gl.createSequentialGroup();
    verticalGroup.addComponent(label).addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED);
    radioButtons.forEach(radioValue -> verticalGroup.addComponent(radioValue));

    gl.setVerticalGroup(verticalGroup);
}

private void textField(JLabel label, JTextField field) {
    GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(this);
    setLayout(gl);

    gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

    gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
            .addComponent(label)
            .addComponent(field)
    );

    gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(label)
            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(field)
    );
}
```

but it looks terrible is not viable:

[image]

While I like the simplicity of the `GroupLayout`, I'm starting to wonder if another layout might be needed. I'm willing to try others, especially `MigLayout`, but if `GroupLayout` can do it, all the better. Any ideas?

Comment: My immediate thought is a `JTable`, but ... `GridBagLayout` would be my next choice

Comment: `JTable` implies using renderer and editor, and you don't want to go that mad road :) I would rather use a `GridBagLayout` but that mean you'll have to create row/col which will have the same width (on a col)/height (on a row). You can also create your own `LayoutManager2` if you really need to.

Comment: *if the horizontal should wrap to the next line if not wide enough.*  - that would imply you use a FlowLayout (or the [WrapLayout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/)) as the main layout.  Then each radio button or text field group would be a separate panel with the required components that you then add to the main panel. But I would say we don't really have enough information to give a more detailed suggestion. For example I don't know if you intend wrapped columns to be the same width as the column above or is each row of components independent from the other?

Comment: I edited the question to avoid the wrapping, @camickr.

Comment: *I edited the question to avoid the wrapping* - not sure it really changes my suggestion. What I see is that for each item in the DSL you have a JLabel on top followed by one or more components below the label. So you could easily create a JPanel using a GridLayout. You add the label and either the text field or multiple radio buttons to the panel. Then you add this panel to a parent panel. The parent panel could use a FlowLayout or a horizontal BoxLayout to display each panel horizontally. My key point is you are not forced to use a single layout manager on a single panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two additional lines of code, the `GridLayout` implementation is now viable by linking the size of all the components:

```
Group horizontalGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
fields.forEach(field -> horizontalGroup.addComponent(field));
layout.setHorizontalGroup(horizontalGroup);

Group verticalGroup = layout.createParallelGroup();
fields.forEach(field -> verticalGroup.addComponent(field));
layout.setVerticalGroup(verticalGroup);

layout.linkSize(fields.toArray(new Component[0]));             // <-- ADDITION
```

and sets the maximum height of the text fields:

```
private void textField(JLabel label, JTextField field) {
    GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(this);
    setLayout(gl);

    field.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, 20));  // <-- ADDITION

    gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

    gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
            .addComponent(label)
            .addComponent(field)
    );

    gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(label)
            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(field)
    );
}
```

[image]